# uwsgi use python3 inside virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, uwsgi, virtualenvwrapper

i have `python 2.7` installed on my ubuntu as default `python` and `uwsgi` for `version 2.7` is installed. but i want to run a **django app** that uses `python 3` so i created a `virtualenv` and installed `python3` & `uwsgi` inside it.

now in my `init.d` file of `uwsgi` i have `DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi` set so i think its using version 2.7 of python and because of which i am getting this error:

```
Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Nov 23 2017, 15:53:45)  [GCC 4.8.4]
Set PythonHome to /root/Env/firstsite
ImportError: No module named site
```

how can i make uwsgi-emperor run `python3` (its installed inside virtualenv)

also i noticed this line in uwsgi upstart file.

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

could this be causing it to run with python2